# Unable to include python3-dev in a core-image-minimal using Yocto Dunfell

Tags: python-3.x, compiler-errors, yocto, bitbake

My build process should include the following layers

```
meta                  /home/cladm1/var-fslc-yocto/sources/poky/meta  5
meta-poky             /home/cladm1/var-fslc-yocto/sources/poky/meta-poky  5
meta-oe               /home/cladm1/var-fslc-yocto/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-oe  6
meta-multimedia       /home/cladm1/var-fslc-yocto/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia  6
meta-python           /home/cladm1/var-fslc-yocto/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-python  7
meta-filesystems      /home/cladm1/var-fslc-yocto/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-filesystems  6
meta-gnome            /home/cladm1/var-fslc-yocto/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-gnome  7
meta-networking       /home/cladm1/var-fslc-yocto/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-networking  5
meta-freescale        /home/cladm1/var-fslc-yocto/sources/meta-freescale  5
meta-freescale-3rdparty  /home/cladm1/var-fslc-yocto/sources/meta-freescale-3rdparty  4
meta-freescale-distro  /home/cladm1/var-fslc-yocto/sources/meta-freescale-distro  4
meta-qt5              /home/cladm1/var-fslc-yocto/sources/meta-qt5  7
meta-swupdate         /home/cladm1/var-fslc-yocto/sources/meta-swupdate  6
meta-virtualization   /home/cladm1/var-fslc-yocto/sources/meta-virtualization  8
meta-variscite-fslc   /home/cladm1/var-fslc-yocto/sources/meta-variscite-fslc  9
meta-iotsec           /home/cladm1/var-fslc-yocto/sources/meta-iotsec  10
meta-python2          /home/cladm1/var-fslc-yocto/sources/meta-python2  7
workspace             /home/cladm1/var-fslc-yocto/build_fb/workspace  99
meta-webos            /home/cladm1/var-fslc-yocto/sources/meta-webosose/meta-webos  40
meta-sca              /home/cladm1/var-fslc-yocto/sources/meta-sca  8
meta-webserver        /home/cladm1/var-fslc-yocto/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-webserver  6
meta-cloud-services   /home/cladm1/var-fslc-yocto/sources/meta-cloud-services  5
meta-openstack        /home/cladm1/var-fslc-yocto/sources/meta-cloud-services/meta-openstack  5
```

where `meta-iotsec` is a custom layer of mine containing some python recipes. I can compile a `core-image-minimal` without any issues unless `python3-dev` is included which is causing the following error

```
Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  696 Packages

Total size: 114 M
Installed size: 556 M
Downloading Packages:
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Error: Transaction check error:
  file /var/db conflicts between attempted installs of libnss-db2-2.31+git0+6fdf971c9d-r0webos6.cortexa7t2hf_neon and base-files-3.0.14-r89webos11.imx6ul_var_dart

Error Summary
-------------


ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/cladm1/var-fslc-yocto/build_fb/tmp/work/imx6ul_var_dart-fslc-linux-gnueabi/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.6417
ERROR: Task (/home/cladm1/var-fslc-yocto/sources/poky/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal.bb:do_rootfs) failed with exit code '1'
```

I'm not able to find any working solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You have tried to install `python3-dev` using the recipe located in `recipes-core/image` via IMAGE_INSTALL_append, right?

Comment: I have no python3-dev recipe in that folder

Comment: It is not necessary to have a recipe specifically named as such, but it must contain what I mentioned above.

Comment: I did it and that will cause the above error

Comment: Try with `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python3-dev"` (not ignore the space). Other option is populate the rootfs with the package using menuconfig task

Comment: How to do for the second option?

Comment: By searching for python3-dev package in the menu available to you with the command `petalinux-config -c rootfs` if you are using petalinux or by using bitbake with `bitbake -c menuconfig linux-xlnx` (in this case it would be for the Xilinx custom kernel) if you are directly using Yocto Project.

Comment: do you mind telling me how to do that? there are a bunch of options but I can't see any Search